# Laravel Factory - use if state in factory

Tags: laravel-5.6

I want to create a Laravel Factory for one of my model . my model have two field **( is_used , update_time )**

I want to fill my **update_time** if the result of **is_used** is equal to 1.

I created my is_used faker like below code and want to fill my update_time whenever my is_used is equal to 1

```
'is_used' => $faker->randomElement([0, 1]),
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `update_time` field can be nullable:

```
$factory->define(SomeModel::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $is_used = $faker->randomElement([0, 1]);
    return [
        'update_time' => $is_used === 1 ? now() : null,
        'is_used' => $is_used,
    ];
});
```